# Wifi equipment for max 100m

Tags: wireless-networking, antenna

I would like to know if consumer grade equipment with a panel antenna can cover about 70 degrees at 60-80meter distance  area without any obstancles for smartphones.

Do i need an expensive cisco for this like aironet 1240? Current tplink access point router inside the building cant go past 15m .(we'll put one outside or near window) There isnt much noise there.
Should i try 802.11n ? I guess that these need other type of antenna.
And is this possible or not

Comment: Have you tried putting your existing router outside? Is the range any better?

Comment: no i havent. but it is a cheap 25eur AP